# Problea con dos lineas en un tab

Tags: android

Hola amigos una consulta estoy estoy haciendo una app en android y estoy necesitando incrustar dos lineas  en el titulo de un tab, el problema es que que cuando incrusto las dos lineas automaticamente el tamaño de la letra se reduce, adjunto imagen, espero me den una mano.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Necesitas que el tamaño se mantenga? Porque se pone a dos lineas para que se pueda leer, de otro modo no se notaria las letras.

Comment: Acostumbra agregar el código de lo que estas realizando para que la comunidad te pueda ayudar de una mejor manera, ¿Como defines dos lineas?